# Undefined index in php css with ajax post

Tags: php, css, ajax, content-management-system, jquery-post

I've trying to solve this for the last five days now, but nothing works. I've viewed every single post on the subject and nothing helps. I am using an OpenCart CMS and would like to send a simple jquery variable from one file to another with ajax and post so it can change the background color of the css file. To make this clear why the file is not with .php extension read this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/supercharge-your-css-with-php-under-the-hood/ especially the Elegant Method. So this is the code of the ajax

```
$(document).ready(
    function() 
      {
        var headerDefaultColor = "#126FA8";
      $.ajax({
        url:  "view/stylesheet/supercharge.css",
        data: {cell: headerDefaultColor},
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("Send");
        },
        error: function(data){
          console.log("Error");
        } 
        })
        .done(function(cell) { console.log("Done success: " + cell); })
        .fail(function() { console.log("error"); })
        .always(function() { console.log("complete"); })
        });
```

This is the code for the css

```
    <?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?> 

<?php
    $headerColor = null;
    var_dump($_POST['cell']);
    if(isset($_POST['cell'])){
        $headerColor = $_POST['cell'];
    } else {
        $headerColor = "Nothing happends, again!!"; 
    }
?>

#header {
    background-color: <?php echo $headerColor;  ?>;
}
```

This is what i get in the console:

```
    Send index.php:103
Done success:  

    <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'#126FA8'</font> <i>(length=7)</i>
    </pre>
    #header {
        background-color: #126FA8;
    }
```

However this is what i get in the css file. It should send the hex code, however it doesn't and it generated a Notice: Undefined index: cell and here is the output:

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: cell in C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\opencart-1.5.5.1\upload\admin\view\stylesheet\supercharge.css on line <i>14</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0004</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>250160</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\opencart-1.5.5.1\upload\admin\view\stylesheet\supercharge.css' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\supercharge.css<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
</pre>
#header {
    background-color: Nothing happends, again!!;
}
```

I tried with isset() and it doesn't work i tried with empty() it doesn't work, and also viewed every singe search result that google gave me nothing works. So i want the var headerDefaultColor to be send to the .css file and change the background color with php and not with jquery (which works fine). What am i missing here?

Comment: Do you mean to do this? $( "#header" ).css( "background-color", headerDefaultColor )

Comment: I don't want it done with JQuery because that is not the point. The   color should be changed via the php variable. I know that the jquery works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP file to this

```
<?php 

header("Content-type: text/css"); 

// checks if cell is received from GET or POST, if not assign default value as #fff
$headerColor = isset($_REQUEST['cell']) ? $_REQUEST['cell'] : '#fff';

?>

#header {
    background-color: <?php echo $headerColor;  ?>;
}
```

When you are calling the CSS file, call it as below

`<link href='view/stylesheet/supercharge.css?cell=#F00' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />`

Comment: Not working i tried the $_REQUEST as well, and the code above in some other posts it's basically the same code as mine.

Comment: Is there a link to your working site? How did you get the last output? If the .htaccess file is set properly, the PHP file should capture the GET variables properly.

Comment: It's a localhost and everything is set by default during the installation. I've made no changes to the main .htaccess file, except i added another .htaccess in the stylesheet folder AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .css.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your url to php file like and not .css as you will get request in php file and not in css file

```
url:  "view/stylesheet/supercharge.php
```

Comment: Tried that as well, i still get the unidentified index: cell in the css/php file when viewed with the cosole. To see how it works read the link tutorial.

Comment: I succeed with changing css, but it seems that the browser do not use new values.

Comment: did you check the path ? means you have your file named supercharge.php in folder view/stylesheet ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not sending two or more ajax requests to the same url in time, as one of them can overrite data sent from second.
E.g.:

```
function first_ajax(searchQuery) {
         $.ajax({
                url: '/search/index.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {query: searchQuery},
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.objD);
                }
            });
};

function second_ajax(searchQuery) {
              first_ajax(searchQuery);    
              $.ajax({
                        url: '/search/index.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {query:searchQuery, paging:paging, start:start},
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            loader.show();
                        },
                        complete: function() {
                            loader.hide();
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                };
    }
```

In this case data sent from second_ajax() "Paging" and "Start" will be undefined index for PHP as they would be overriten with first_ajax()